# Node-sass not compiling on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, node-modules, node-sass

I've deployed my React app onto Azure and i'm currently getting this compilation error when loading up the site:

```
./src/components/LoadingScreen/LoadingScreen.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/components/LoadingScreen/LoadingScreen.scss)
Error: Missing binding /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

I've tried to run `npm rebuild node-sass` in several places but have had no luck so far. Is this happening because it's being built with Windows but deployed onto a Linux machine? How can I fix this?

Comment: delete ```node-sass``` folder under ```node_modules``` then execute ```npm install```

Comment: cool, i made it as answer , please accept that as a correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete `node-sass` folder under `node_modules` then execute `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try running npm rebuild node-sass after the build in production if the commented answer doesn't work. I believe this error occurs in Docker containers if the node-sass was installed in a separate OS environment (ie windows/linux).  So you could run `npm run start npm rebuild node-sass`  so it rebuilds  in the correct environment.

If you do delete and rebuild,  itt might also be useful to run a npm install on your prod environment BEFORE you do it in development.